# Problem with Swift version using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

> SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. (in target 'Alamofire')

I am getting this message and my app build fails. Kindly help me out as I have all things up to date.

Comment: you need to update Alamofire version... try to update pod for your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your POD's project Settings, select your target (Alamofire in this case), then in the Build Settings Section, search for swift language version and change it to 4.2